# Ranking row values from a multiplus row dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stack, ranking

I have a huge `df` that looks like this:

| date | stock1 | stock2 | stock3 | stock4 | stock5 | stock6 | stock7 | stock8 | stock9 | stock10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10/20 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.3 | 0.4 | 0.5 | 0.6 | 0.7 | 0.8 | 0.9 | 0.9 |
| 11/20 | 0.8 | 0.9 | 0.3 | 0.4 | 0.3 | 0.5 | 0.3 | 0.2 | 0.4 | 0.1 |
| 12/20 | 0.3 | 0.6 | 0.9 | 0.5 | 0.6 | 0.7 | 0.8 | 0.7 | 0.9 | 0.1 |

I want to find, for each row, the 20% higher values of stocks and the 20% lower. The output should be:

| date | higher | lower |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10/20 | stock9, stock 10 | stock1, stock 2 |
| 11/20 | stock1, stock 2 | stock8, stock 10 |
| 12/20 | stock3, stock 9 | stock1, stock 10 |

I do not need to have the comma between the values above, could be one below the other.
I have tried `df= df.stack()` for stacking and later rank the values inside the columns, but I do not know how to proceed.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "20% higher values"? Do you want the 2 highest and 2 lowest?

Comment: I mean the 20% of the highest. In this case, it is the 2 highest and 2 lowest because there are only 10 values. But in my original I have around 2000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `nlargest` and `nsmallest`:

```
#df = df.set_index("date") #uncomment if date is a column and not the index
n = round(len(df.columns)*0.2) #number of stocks in the top/bottom 20%

output = pd.DataFrame()
output["higher"] = df.apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(n).index.tolist(), axis=1)
output["lower"] = df.apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(n).index.tolist(), axis=1)

>>> output
                  higher              lower
date                                       
10/20  [stock9, stock10]   [stock1, stock2]
11/20   [stock2, stock1]  [stock10, stock8]
12/20   [stock3, stock9]  [stock10, stock1]
```

Edit:
If you want each stock name on a separate line, you can do:

```
output = pd.DataFrame()
output["higher"] = df.apply(lambda x: "\n".join(x.nlargest(n).index.tolist()), axis=1)
output["lower"] = df.apply(lambda x: "\n".join(x.nsmallest(n).index.tolist()), axis=1)
```

Comment: I get the "KeyError: "None of ['date'] are in the columns". I executed "df.columns" and there is no column called "date". However, I can see it when I display the dataset. I am going to add a screenshot on my post.

Comment: It is probably the index. Ignore the first line and do the rest then

Comment: Now it has worked, thanks. How could I have the formation in a way that the names are not divided by comma, but is each of them a line?

Comment: @user17717499 - I edited my answer but I would suggest not to do that as accessing the elements later on will be easier with the list format.

Comment: That is one more thing I have not taken into account before: the number of observations for each row are different, and so, the "size" is different for each row. For example, if a row has 100 observations, I need 20 values in the "higher" and 20 in the "lower". But if the row has 200 observations, then I will have double amount of values for "higher" and "lower". Do you know how could I integrate that into the code?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a helper function that sorts values for each row:

```
def get_top_bottom_20_pct(x):
    d = x.sort_values(ascending=False).index.tolist()
    return [*map(', '.join, (d[:size], d[-size:]))]

size = int(0.2 * df.shape[1])
s = df.set_index('date').apply(get_top_bottom_20_pct, axis=1)
out = pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(), index=s.index, columns=['higher','lower']).reset_index()
```

If you have Python >=3.8, you can do the same with the walrus operator:

```
s = df.set_index('date').apply(lambda x: (', '.join((d := x.sort_values(ascending=False).index.tolist())[:size]), 
                                          ', '.join(d[-size:])), axis=1)
out = pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(), index=s.index, columns=['higher','lower']).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    date           higher            lower
0  10/20  stock9, stock10   stock2, stock1
1  11/20   stock2, stock1  stock8, stock10
2  12/20   stock3, stock9  stock1, stock10
```

Comment: That is one more thing I have not taken into account before: the number of observations for each row are different, and so, the "size" is different for each row. For example, if a row has 100 observations, I need 20 values in the "higher" and 20 in the "lower". But if the row has 200 observations, then I will have double amount of values for "higher" and "lower". Do you know how could I integrate that into the code?